# Sorting Python dictionary based on number of items in list

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I have a small script in Python with a dictionary same as follows:

```
d = {'category_1' : ['a', 'b'], 
'category_2' : ['c', 'd', 'e'],
'category_3' : ['z']}
```

How can I sort it based on number of values in list? I want it looks like:

```
d = {'category_3' : ['z'], 
'category_1' : ['a', 'b'], 
'category_2' : ['c', 'd', 'e']}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dictionaries in Python are orderless.

In order to actually store ordering, you will need to either have a list of tuples, or use a [`collections.OrderedDict()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: len(item[1])))
OrderedDict([('category_3', ['z']), ('category_1', ['a', 'b']), ('category_2', ['c', 'd', 'e'])])
```

The ordering is achieved here by using [the `sorted()` built-in](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#sorted), with a simple `key` function.

Comment: or `key=lambda (k,v): len(v)` (for Python2)

Comment: @gnibbler Only in 2.x though.

Comment: @Lattyware, unfortunately it's one use case I miss with 3, although 2to3 should rewrite it ok to `key=lambda k_v: len(k_v[1])`, `item` is more readable than `k_v`